# For DT in shiny, how to use FormatStyle and Extension at the same time ?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

Simply speaking, I colored the cell to gray if it is larger than 0, then in the formatted table, I want to display row names and edit the table.

The following is part of my code

```
  output$date_wrong_out = renderDataTable(
    datatable(date_wrong(),
          # Hide logical columns
           options=list(
             columnDefs = list(list(targets=date_check_data[['hind_con']],
                                               visible=F)),
          sDom  = '<"top">lrt<"bottom">ip'),
          editable = TRUE,
          selection = 'none',
          rownames = FALSE
           ) %>%
  # Format data columns based on the values of hidden logical columns
  formatStyle(columns = date_check_data[['show']],
              valueColumns = date_check_data[['hind']],
              color = styleInterval(0, c('black','white')),
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c( 'white','gray'))
```

)
  )

It works perfectly fine if I don't have these three lines

```
editable = TRUE,
selection = 'none',
rownames = FALSE
```

But when I added them, shiny didn't show my table at all. I guess I just don't where is the right place to put them.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this work for me by taking out 
`rownames = FALSE`

Maybe rownames and columnDefs has conflict. I don't know for sure